# How to call a method of another class from onAuthenticationSucceeded method?

Tags: android, fingerprint

I have used a fingerprint login in my android app.

- If the authentication success,it will call the onAuthenticationSucceeded method.
- After a success authentication of fingerprint I want to verify the username within the onAuthenticationSucceeded.
- But I couldn't call a method(for verifying username) of another class within onAuthenticationSucceeded method.

The app always seems to be stopped.

How could I acheive it?
Please help me.
Thank you

- this is in my FingerprintHandler.java

  `public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult result{

  login log=new login();   log.unameCheck();
  }`
- this is the method in login.java

`public void unameCheck(){

 String uname=edit_username.getText().toString(); 
String storedPassword=myDb.getSingleEntry(uname);

if(storedPassword!=0){  Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login Successfull",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

 Intent intent =new Intent("michel.maan.login1");    startActivity(intent);.      } 
else { 
Toast.makeText(login.this,"Login failed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); } }`

- this is my Databasehelper.java

  `public String getSingleEntry(String userName){

  SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();

  Cursor cursor=db.query("USER_TABLE".null,"NAME=?",new String[]{username},null,null,null);    if(cursor.getCount()<1){

  cursor.close();

  return"NOT EXIST" ;    }  cursor.moveToFirst();
  String password=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("PASSWORD"));  cursor.close();

  return password;    }`
- the exception showing in android monitor is

  `Java.lang.NullPointerExceptio:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference`

[This is the code I referred for my project from android authority](http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-add-fingerprint-authentication-to-your-android-app-747304/)

Answer (score 2):

simplest way would be to startActivity on onAuthenticatinSucceed method and pass a extra with that intent

```
Intent intent=new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("authentication","done");
startActivity(intent);
```

and now in onCreate of secondActiviy get this extra and check like this

```
if(getIntent.getExtra("authentication").equals("done"))
 callVerifyUsername();
```

and if you want you can also pass username from the FingerprintActivity as extra in intent.
if you want to get back to previous screen if userName is not verified you can simply call

```
finish();
```

Comment: I afraid that it couldn't be done. FingerprintHandler.java is called from login activity.

Comment: when you want to verify user from the same class , why are you writing it in other class. make it simple by writing it in the same class.

Comment: You are right!  I moved the methods from FingeprintHandler class to Login class.Now It's working!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create instance of the class and call the method :

```
  void onAuthenticationSucceeded ( ... ) { //in your  onAuthenticationSucceeded method 
  ...
   yourAnotherClass newInstance = new  yourAnotherClass(...); //Make Instance of your verfying class 
   newInstance.verfyUserName (...); //call the Verifying Method

   }
```

Comment: I had tried it,but the verfyUsername() method cannot be called.

Comment: Login log=new Login();

Comment: log.unameCheck();

Comment: are you declaring it as static Method?? ,it would be better to show your code

Comment: unameCheck is my method in Login class

Comment: is it static or non-static method ?

Comment: No,but I found that there is no onCreate method in my Fingerprinthelper class.Is that a problem?

Comment: It is not static.Sir,I cant include picture of code due to low reputation.

Comment: No ,it's not the problem ,onCreate Methode is anly overridden in classes that extends App Activity or MainActivity class .the problem is that either you declare the method as static or something else relates to the class itselft 
the best way to know is to surround your code by Try ,Catch statment and tell me what is the caught exception then .

Comment: I had tried try-catch statement inside onAuthenticationSucceeded.It seems that app is not stopping now,but unameCheck() method is not still loading.

Comment: my friend ,give me what is the exception you got befor you but the try catch ,try catch hadles exception in a proper way ,but now i need to know the exception ,remove try catch and tell me what is the exception

Comment: Java.lang.NullPointerExceptio:Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.Resources android.content.Context.getResources()' on a null object reference

Comment: Good, that's  it you are referring  the Method (getResources)   to A null Context Object  edit your question and put the code then i can you what to change

Comment: Please re-edit your  code properly , add 4 spaces before each code line

Comment: you sure you don't have syntax  errors, it seems to me that your code is not totally clean.... public void onAuthenticationSucceeded(FingerprintManager.AuthenticationResult **//here you need a beaket** result{

Comment: And here you have a semicolon  which must  not be here **public void unameCheck();**

Comment: And here instead of writing **login** you are writing **log**  here **log.unameCheck();**

Comment: And from where do you pass the edit_username to your login. Java

Comment: From an EditText  in the UI

Answer (score 0):

Make object of your other class in your authentication class and call that method using that object like below

Suppose your method name is, VerifyUserName(), and it is in SecondActivity then in your firstActivity at authentication succeeded, do like below

```
SecondActivity sa = new SecondActivity();
sa.VerifyUSerName();
```

Comment: I had tried it,but the unameCheck () is not calling.

Comment: What that method has?
Does it return Boolean Value??

Comment: public void unameCheck() method for verifying username from the database and toast a message if success.